# Finding largest value from String in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string column (`cmpstn_val`) which has values with decimal points embedded - like this:

```
cust_nm | cmpstn_val
--------+------------------------
John    | 123.384501928340000
Mark    | 443.827345985
Peter   | 145.320004
Mike    | 678.293845012000000010
```

Firstly, I have to consider only the part that appears **after** the dot (.) and secondly, I have to find out which of these values has the **highest number of digits** present after the dot (.), and print the corresponding record which contains that value.

Hence, for the example presented above the SQL query should return the last value (i.e. '`678.293845012000000010`') since it has the highest number of digits/characters after the decimal point.

```
cust_nm | cmpstn_val
--------+------------------------
Mike    | 678.293845012000000010
```

Comment: Why are you storing decimal values in a `varchar` in the first place?

Comment: What do you want to do if there is a tie (two or more rows with the same, highest number of digits after the decimal)? Return both? If not, you need to define a tiebreaker.

Comment: What is the issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

One method is:

```
select len(stuff(cmpstn_val, 1, charindex('.', cmpstn_val), '')) as num_digits_after_dot
```

If you want the longest one:

```
select top (1) t.*
from t
order by len(stuff(cmpstn_val, 1, charindex('.', cmpstn_val), '')) desc;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=52c6fa990dc7ccbd8f0b2c6145358160) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Using `parsename` with `len`. This one works if the string after the decimal is at most 128 characters.

```
select top (1) *
from t
order by len(parsename(cmpstn_val,1)) desc;
```

This one is probably more reliable since the string before decimal looks more likely to be shorter

```
select top (1) *
from t
order by len(cmpstn_val)-len(parsename(cmpstn_val,2)) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different way to use `parsename`, return that portion also, filter out any values that don't contain a decimal, and optionally deal with ties.

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT *, digits = PARSENAME(cmpstn_val,1)
  FROM dbo.tablename 
  WHERE cmpstn_val LIKE '%.%'
)
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES 
  * FROM x 
  ORDER BY LEN(digits) DESC;
```

Results given the sample data in the question:

```
cust_nm    cmpstn_val                digits
=======    ======================    ==================
Mike       678.293845012000000010    293845012000000010
```

But I agree with [@Larnu's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63581399/finding-largest-value-from-string-in-sql-server/63582707#comment112432238_63581399), you shouldn't be storing decimals as strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String functions`.`CHARINDEX function` - to get '.' position in the field (`CHARINDEX('.',cmpstn_val`) and
then
using `SUBSTRING function` - we cut the string from the dot till the end (`SUBSTRING(cmpstn_val,CHARINDEX('.',cmpstn_val)+1,LEN(cmpstn_val))`).At last just get the `LEN`(number of digits):

```
 SELECT  TOP(1) WITH TIES *, 
 LEN(SUBSTRING(cmpstn_val,CHARINDEX('.',cmpstn_val)+1,LEN(cmpstn_val))) len_val from Table
ORDER BY len_val DESC
```